# can't run iOS project in simulator nor device

Tags: ios, xcode

I made some changes in my xcode project, which somehow, causes me to not be able to run the app in the simulator nor device. The only option that I can see now is My Mac 64 bit. How do I fix this? The target is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the project in XCode (4.4.1), on the left top click the folder icon, then select your project icon to bring up the project settings page.  Click on the "Summary" tab, then you should see "Devices" where you can select the device you want to target.

If that doesn't work (you don't see "iOS Application Target") you may need to go into "Build Settings" and select a different "Base SDK" -- I usually select "Latest iOS".  You may have selected a Mac OS X SDK.  Also check "Supported Platforms" to select "iOS".

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

Go to Edit scheme (Drop down near the stop button), then select Excecutable as "yourapp.app".

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me. I'm on Xcode 6.1.1, and had just done a "pod update" to update AFNetworking from version 2.0.2 to 2.5.1. When I reopened the workspace it was like I had switched to a Mac app even though base SDK and deployment target still showed iOS. But this made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another Way which did it for me ...

go to manage Schemes and click `Autocreate schemes now` on the upper left side ..

hope it helps